# Percentage value on firebase web performance distribution graphs

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I'm reading my reports from firebase web performance and I don't understand what means the percentage value in the **distribution graph**.

Bellow a print of the loadEventEnd with the graph.

[loadEventEnd-report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofG7Y.png)

Is the value **95%** represents users affected with the load time of 11.85s?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing there is the **95th Percentile** number. That means that if you ordered all events from fastest to slowest, **five percent of all requests took 11.85s or longer**.

Percentile metrics are very useful for measuring performance problems in the margins -- your median load time may be great, but if 5% of users are experiencing a very long load time, it might be worth trying to dig into why and optimizing it more.

A great exercise might be to use the filters that are available to try to find a cohort of users for whom the *median* number is closer to that 95p number -- for instance, a specific browser or geographical region. That will give you more insight into who exactly is having a slower experience on your site.